# Architecting token-based authentication for a three-tier application running on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am designing an application that will consist of:

- SPA written in React, deployed to an instance of Azure App Service
- REST API written in .Net Core Web API, deployed to another instance of Azure App Service
- Azure SQL Database in the same Azure tenant as the app services above

All these resources will be connected to the same instance of Azure AD (also in the same tenant).

Conceptually, I suppose the authentication could work roughly like this:

- The user connection to the SPA and obtains an auth token
- The token would then be passed to the API and then the API will use that token to authenticate the user to the SQL Database (this [seems possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#azure-ad-token))

However, I have not been able to find any walkthroughs or other documentation that would demonstrate this seemingly straightforward way of implementing authentication. Seems like this is a typical enough scenario for it to be widely documented by bloggers or Microsoft itself, so not being able to find it makes me wonder if I am not thinking about this right, or maybe I am not looking in the right places.

Can someone please help me figure out what is the right way to approach this and point me to some online resources that could guide me through this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much more common for the REST API to use its Managed Service Identity to obtain a token for Azure SQL Database, and use that.  It's always been rare for web apps to use the browser user's identity to connect to SQL Server.

See, eg: [Tutorial: Secure Azure SQL Database connection from App Service using a managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi)

Comment: Great, thank you. This indeed seems like the way to go.

Comment: quick question about the link above. I followed the tutorial and everything works great, but it seems that even after the code is switched to use token-based auth with service principal identity, the connection string still needs to have sql credentials saved in it. It seems that the code needs them to connect to the master database, because if I remove them, the error I get is `Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string.` Am I missing something again?

Comment: I think that may be an Entity Framework Database Initializer.  If so, try turning off the initializer with `Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);`

Comment: I already had that line, actually (as instructed by the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#modify-aspnet-code)). So it must be something else...

Comment: What's the call stack and full exception details?  Are you using Entity Framework Migrations?

Comment: Bizarrely, the issues stopped happening. I tried a few things (like granting the service principal access to master db), but reverted them all, and now could not get the error back. Not sure what's going on. But yes -- I did have Migrations there. I pretty much followed the tutorial to the letter, except in the end I went to remove sysadmin credentials from the pubxml and that's when the app broke. But it's working now. Not sure what's going on. Thank you for the help though!